# add class directly to the datepicker input tag in react JS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

Here I want to add class to the input element directly.[image]

add class with this MuiInputBase-input.
this is code for date picker

```
import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";


render() {
        return (<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={MomentUtils}>
            <DateTimePicker value={this.state.selectedDateTime} onChange={this.OnChangeHandler} className="mh-Dateinput" />
        </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>)
    }
```

Comment: can you provide full code of your component, So I can run locally and check?

Comment: Did you take a look at [`<DateTimePicker>`’s `renderInput*` property](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-time-picker/#props)? It allows you to forward props to the actual `<TextField>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `inputProps` inside `renderInput`.

> Please note that `params` is being used here to apply MUIs parameters to the input field such as value so it behaves as expected.

```
  <DateTimePicker
    ...
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        inputProps={{ className: "custom-class" }}
      />
    )}
  />
```

[image]